# Webjars + Springboot. Custom resource path

Tags: java, spring-boot, webjars

I have a Spring Boot application which acts as a server for my frontend, built by webpack and included into my spring boot web archive.

I use **webjars** to access my frontend scripts and contents.

But there is one problem. To access webjars resources I need to use pathes like:

`/webjars/jar-file-name/resource-name.ext`

When in my react-js frontend code I use relateve pathes:

`/resource-name.ext`

I want to rebind paths of webjars to serve all resources `/**` from `/webjars/jar-file-name`

I have used this do to do it https://www.webjars.org/documentation#springmvc, but this seems to not work with Spring Boot

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/jar-file-name/");
  }
}
```

It should work with Spring MVC, but don't work in Spring Boot.

Could you please advice the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code would resolve your issue:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }
}
```

Here is my static content serving URL for bootstrap 3.1.0 from [tutorial](https://www.webjars.org/documentation#springmvc): `http://localhost:8080/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Does not work for me. I have resources on the same URLs as it was. 

I have checked with a debugger that this line is reached. Seems it works with Spring MVC only. (I use Spring Boot)